# Why does EF throw an error with LastOrDefault in Include operations but not with OrderByDescending?

Tags: c#, .net, database, entity-framework-core

I need to get the last record from the **Monitoring** table

```
return await _context.Applications
                .Include(s => s.Elements)
                .ThenInclude(d => d.Monitoring.LastOrDefault())
                .ToListAsync();
```

But EF throw an error :

```
System.InvalidOperationException: The expression 's.Elements.AsQueryable().LastOrDefault()' is invalid inside an 'Include' operation, since it does not represent a property access: 't => t.MyProperty'. 
To target navigations declared on derived types, use casting ('t => ((Derived)t).MyProperty') or the 'as' operator ('t => (t as Derived).MyProperty'). 
Collection navigation access can be filtered by composing Where, OrderBy(Descending), ThenBy(Descending), Skip or Take operations.
```

But when I execute the same request with **OrderByDescending** it works fine.

```
return await _context.Applications
                .Include(s => s.Elements)
                .ThenInclude(d => d.Monitoring.OrderByDescending(c => c.Id))
                .ToListAsync();
```

Can anyone explain what is the difference between using *OrderByDescending* and *LastOrDefault*?

How would it be correct to get the last item in this case?

Comment: Duplicated question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39692360/linq-to-entities-does-not-recognize-the-method-lastordefault

Comment: @DA this is not duplicate for the linked one. Also EF Core supports (at least latest version) `LastOrDefault`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The difference is that support for one is implemented and for another - is not. This is documented in the EF Core docs for [Filtered Include](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data/eager#filtered-include):

> Supported operations are: `Where`, `OrderBy`, `OrderByDescending`, `ThenBy`, `ThenByDescending`, `Skip`, and `Take`.

So you can do:

```cs
return await _context.Applications
    .Include(s => s.Elements)
    .ThenInclude(d => d.Monitoring.OrderByDescending(c => c.Id).Take(1))
    .ToListAsync();
```

Which should result in `Monitoring` having at most one element with largest `Id`.

Comment: This solution seems to work well. Now I only get the last record from the Monitoring table. Thank you @Guru Stron

Answer (score 0):

The exception describes your problem almost perfectly.
`Include` or `ThenInclude` can't accept an `object`, which is a result of `LastOrDefault()`.

When you you call `OrderByDescending` instead, it's still a property accessor which can be converted by EF to the SQL code - also, it's a pointer to the collection.

Try to convert your code directly to the SQL code, how can you perform "JOIN" with a single row (this is what `LastOrDefault` tries to perform) ? - you can't.

The difference between `LastOrDefault` and `OrderByDescending` is that first one, results in a single record, and another one results in a collection, ordered by your preference.

Comment: _"When you you call OrderByDescending instead, it's still a property accessor"_ - no, it is not, it is a method call expression invoked on property accessor.